# Docker/Boot2Docker: Set HTTP/HTTPS proxies for docker on OS X

Tags: macos, proxy, docker, boot2docker

**In short**: How can I set the HTTP/HTTPS proxies for Docker on Mac OS X?

**In detail**:

I run Docker (1.12) on Mac OS X behind a proxy. I followed the [installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/) and installed boot2docker. This is working fine if I pull from my network-internal Docker registry.

However, I get the following error when pulling from docker.io:

```
machine:~ me$ docker run ubuntu echo hello world
Unable to find image 'ubuntu' locally
Pulling repository ubuntu
2014/06/30 13:23:26 Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/ubuntu/images:
dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: no such host
```

**Note 1**: `DOCKER_HOST`, `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` are available in the environment (running `env` displays all three).

**Note 2**: I read in other posts that this error occurs when the daemon is not running properly. However, `docker version` doesn't show any problems. Moreover, I can pull and run images pulled from my network-internal Docker registry.

**Note 3**: I was able to set up Docker on [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) (RHEL). I had to add the proxy information to `/etc/sysconfig/docker`. I read that there is a similar file on Ubuntu (`/etc/init/docker.conf`). However, I could not find that file for Docker (or boot2docker?) on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The config files you need to modify won't be on your OS X file system, they'll be attached to the Tiny Core Linux VM which acts as your local Docker server.

To configure the proxy for that, first start Boot2docker from Applications.  Once it's started, get a terminal window and ssh into the VM:

```
bash-3.2$ boot2docker ssh
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:2022' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
                        ##        .
                  ## ## ##       ==
               ## ## ## ##      ===
           /""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o          __/
             \    \        __/
              \____\______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
boot2docker: 1.0.1
             master : cad5ece - Fri Jun 20 02:03:40 UTC 2014
docker@boot2docker:~$
```

Now create/modify /var/lib/boot2docker/profile to set proxy info:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
```

Tinycore needs the proxy info as follows:  protocol://ip:port
To be safe I set proxies for both HTTP and HTTPS.

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://your.proxy.name:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://your.proxy.name:8080
```

Now you can restart the VM docker service and exit the VM.

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
docker@boot2docker:~$ exit
Connection to localhost closed.
```

You should be able to run the client against the VM instance now.

```
bash-3.2$ docker search ubuntu
NAME                                             DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
ubuntu                                           Official Ubuntu base image                      356                  
stackbrew/ubuntu                                 Official Ubuntu base image                      39                   
crashsystems/gitlab-docker                       A trusted, regularly updated build of GitL...
```

This change is persisted through VM restarts.  You should only need to do it once.

For the record, VirtualBox has a global preference setting for proxies but nothing I tried there would work.

Comment: This also fixed my input lag problem somehow

Comment: should these proxy settings then show in your `env`? and should the `profile` file be called `.profile`?

Comment: In our case after this we had to run `boot2docker down` and `boot2docker up`.

Comment: Just for the recored, the problem is also discussed at https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/102

Answer (score 18):

As of the recent (August 2015) 1.8 release, docker's recommended way to create docker hosts - including boot2docker VMs - is through its *docker-machine* utility.

And also since version 1.8, docker-machine now supports the configuration of the proxies at VM creation time via an invocation like the following:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
    --engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://192.37.246.181:2010 \
    --engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.37.246.181:2010 \
    --engine-env NO_PROXY=novartis.net \
    default
```

This results in a VM that has the specified environment variables already added to the initialization file /var/lib/boot2docker/profile - no need to manually add them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting proxy config in .profile file:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ vi ~/.profile
```

add your proxy at the end:

```
#
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
PAGER='less -EM'
MANPAGER='less -isR'

EDITOR=vi

export PS1 PAGER FILEMGR EDITOR MANPAGER

export BACKUP=1
[ "`id -un`" = "`cat /etc/sysconfig/tcuser`" ] && echo "$BACKUP" | sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/backup >/dev/null 2>&1
export FLWM_TITLEBAR_COLOR="58:7D:AA"

if [ -f "$HOME/.ashrc" ]; then
   export ENV="$HOME/.ashrc"
   . "$HOME/.ashrc"
fi

TERMTYPE=`/usr/bin/tty`
[ ${TERMTYPE:5:3} == "tty" ] && (
[ ! -f /etc/sysconfig/Xserver ] ||
[ -f /etc/sysconfig/text ] ||
[ -e /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 ] ||
startx
)

export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.XX.com:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.XX.com:8080
```

finally, restart your Boot2Docker.

Comment: +1 I wasn't able to start `Boot2Docker start`, as it couldn't download the req'd ISO. By setting aforementioned Environment Variables (in Windows7), I was able to get it working!

Comment: in my case, none of the changes I make to ~/.ashrc & ~/.profile are ever persisted. I tried tcl filetool.sh to backup, nothing works.. I'm totally puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) and are behind a proxy environment.

Click on the docker icon on top menu bar. (like shown in step 1.3 [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) )

Go to `Preferences > Advanced` and set the proxy in HTTP  and HTTPS options there. Click Apply and Restart below it. You are good to go. :)

Comment: And make sure that you use the fully qualified path including the protocol. `http://<user:pass>@<domain>`

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem with curl in docker build, I added the following inside the Dockerfile:

```
ENV http_proxy=http://infoprx2:8080
ENV https_proxy=http://infoprx2:8080
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl vim
```

Note that the ENV statement is BEFORE the RUN statement.

and in order to make the docker daemon able to access the internet (I use kitematic with boot2docker), I added the following into /var/lib/boot2docker/profile :

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://infoprx2:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://infoprx2:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

The config file in boot2docker should be `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`, edit this file to custom http(s) proxy.