# Running Boot2docker behind proxy, getting FATA[0020] Forbidden for any interaction with Docker hub

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Followed the [instruction to set up proxy of boot2docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489265/docker-boot2docker-set-http-https-proxies-for-docker-on-osx)  , Getting the following FATAs, any clue

`FATA[0020] Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/busybox/images: Forbidden` while trying to pulling images

```
FATA[0020] Error response from daemon: Server Error: Post https://index.docker.io/v1/users/: Forbidden  while trying to login
```

`FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=ubuntu: Forbidden`  - while searching for images

**updated to include  result of curl -v https://index.docker.io:443**

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://index.docker.io:443/
* About to connect() to proxy 34363bd0dd54 port 8099 (#0)
* Trying 192.168.59.3...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x9adbad8
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x9adbad8) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to 34363bd0dd54 (192.168.59.3) port 8099 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to index.docker.io:443
> CONNECT index.docker.io:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: index.docker.io:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: squid/3.4.9
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 17:56:22 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 3151
< X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
< Vary: Accept-Language
< Content-Language: en
< X-Cache: MISS from localhost
< Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/3.4.9)
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
* Connection #0 to host 34363bd0dd54 left intact
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Looks like it is a proxy issue, I am running a proxy server on the host machine, accessing it by it`s host name in boot2docker VM 's http_proxy and https_proxy but`curl host_proxy:port`  works with no issues

Comment: Can you try `docker login`? Although, it shouldn't be required, your error message says `Forbidden  while trying to login`.

Comment: did all of that , 'login` was one of  those interaction

Comment: Can you please include the result of `curl -v https://index.docker.io:443`, in your question? It would help users understand your proxy server is working properly.

Comment: included  the `curl -v https://index.docker.io:443` result

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue where I would get a 403 error when trying to get lxc-docker to install from get.docker.com (it failed because it could not complete `apt-get update`. In my case, I have the following setup:

- **VM Provider:** VirtualBox (Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty))
- **Environment:** Vagrant
- **Provisioner:** chef-zero (via Vagrant)
- **PROXY:** At first I had forgotten about this, but I am running `apt-cacher-ng` on my host machine (my Macbook Pro) to keep data downloads to a minimum when I'm running apt-get install on Vagrant VM's. In a nutshell, apt-cacher-ng sets up an apt mirror on my Mac for Ubuntu VM's to pull packages from.

I realized that `apt-cacher-ng` doesn't support SSL repositories (https), but does support normal http repositories. Since the Docker repository uses https, I had to find a workaround.

Before I fixed anything, I had the following in my `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10mirror` file in my Ubuntu VM's (localip is the IP address of my Mac which runs the apt-cacher-ng server):

`Acquire::http { Proxy "http://#{localip}:3142"; };`

The above line means my Ubuntu VM's were getting packages through apt-cacher-ng, but failing when a repository used https. By adding the following line beneath that line, things then started to work normally:

`Acquire::https { Proxy \false"; };`

At this point, the contents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10mirror` are as follows:

`Acquire::http { Proxy "http://#{localip}:3142"; };`

`Acquire::https { Proxy \false"; };`

Now, run `apt-get update` and then Docker installs successfully and I'm back to normal testing. In case you are using Vagrant to set up the 10mirror file, here are the lines I have in my Vagrantfile which do the job:

```html
oak.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo 'Acquire::http { Proxy \"http://#{localip}:3142\"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10mirror"
oak.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo 'Acquire::https { Proxy \"false\"; };' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10mirror";
```