# docker-machine behind corporate proxy

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am trying to use docker-machine to create an instance on a private cloud (Openstack) that is behind a corporate http proxy.

Is it possible to tell docker-machine to use the proxy or do I need to have a glance image that is already pre-configure with the http_proxy env variable?

Comment: this should fix your issue. https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/8f82b762749bb8dcf52c6dd0774b927510c5e885/docs/reference/create.md

Comment: Indeed it does. I think it was added with v0.4.0 and was not available with v0.3.0, thanks. Wanna post it as an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As previously mentioned, you can edit the file at

```
$HOME\.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json
```

and set the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY variables (or delete them):

```
 "HostOptions": {
        "Driver": "",
        ...
        "EngineOptions": {
           ...
            "Env": [
              "HTTP_PROXY=http://10.121.8.110:8080",
              "HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.121.8.110:8080",
              "NO_PROXY=192.168.23.4"
            ],
```

After the file has edited, you only have to execute:

```
docker-machine provision
```

Comment: This applies to the engine and is needed for example to pull images.

Comment: what if there is currently no default provisioned and there is no "machines" folder inside $HOME\.docker\machine\ ?

Answer (score 28):

With current docker machine version, I can't find better way to do the change as in boot2docker ([Docker/Boot2Docker: Set HTTP/HTTPS proxies for docker on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489265/docker-boot2docker-set-http-https-proxies-for-docker-on-osx))

If you manually set the proxy in /var/lib/boot2docker/profile in docker machine, after restart it, the proxy setting will be removed automatically.

So I have to create a docker machine with `--engine-env` set for proxy

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
    --engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:8080 \
    --engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://example.com:8080 \
    --engine-env NO_PROXY=example2.com \
    proxybox
```

#### NOTES:

> This is a two-years-old answer, there are a lot of changes happened in
>   docker, so if you still can't make it work behind the proxy, please
>   read [@Senri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39734908/177800) and others.

Documentation: [create docker machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/8f82b762749bb8dcf52c6dd0774b927510c5e885/docs/reference/create.md)

Comment: If you're using something like [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) to create a proxy on your host machine's `localhost`, you'll need to set the VM's proxy to `http://10.0.2.2:<host's proxy port>` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine)).

Comment: Just editing `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` didn't work for me. @Senri's solution worked though.

Comment: Reasonable, the updates in docker happens every day, we can't catch all changes in time, I will remove the update part.

Answer (score 5):

Existing docker-machine config can be modified to add environment for the proxy. The config.json at $HOME/.docker/machine/machines//.config.json can be edited.

Add "HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:8080" to Env in config.json. Restart the machine, and you are all set.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already the machine (VM) created, you can configure the proxy like this :

```
1- SSH into the docker dev host: docker-machine ssh dev
2- Add the following lines to /var/lib/boot2docker/profile (this file is read-only, use sudo)
    export HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy>:<port>
    export HTTPS_PROXY=http://<proxy>:<port>
3- Exit the ssh session and restart the docker machine: docker-machine restart dev
```

[Source](https://toedter.com/2015/05/11/docker-on-windows-behind-a-firewall/)

Comment: This worked for me!!!... I tried the above and it did not work for me... I dont know why

Answer (score 3):

As of Docker 18.09, we can specify environment vars such as proxy to the container on the command line like so:

`docker run  --env HTTP_PROXY="172.10.13.14" -it myImage:latest /bin/bash`

Additionally, we can specify these settings to the docker client by writing them in `~/.docker/config.json` file like so:

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

More information is available on the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client).

Comment: This seems to only affect newly started containers, but has no effect on the engine itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the Docker-machine behind the corporate proxy:

**Linux (Ubuntu, Debian):**

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
cd /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
sudo touch http-proxy.conf
sudo nano http-proxy.conf

# copy and paste in the file:
[Service] 
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://<PROXYIP>:3128"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://<PROXYIP>:3128"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,192.168.1.0/16,10.*.*.*" 

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
sudo systemctl show --property=Environment docker
```

**Windows:**

Update environment variable using Powershell (with admin rights):

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://<PROXYIP>:3128", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", "http://<PROXYIP>:3128", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NO_PROXY", "192.168.*.*, 172.24.*.*, 172.25.*.*, 10.*.*.*, localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0/8", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
Restart-Service docker
```