# Where is the install location of the Windows Boot2Docker Image?

Tags: windows, docker, installation, boot2docker, iso

I have proxy issues when creating a new docker machine on a Windows 10 Enterprise with the docker Toolbox installed:

```
docker-machine create -d hyperv mymachine
```

The following error message appears(formatted for better readablilty):

> (mymachine) Unable to get the latest Boot2Docker ISO release version:
>
> Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest:
>   dial tcp 192.30.253.116:443:
>
> connectex: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond.

I downloaded the Boot2Docker.iso Image from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases.

Now i just Need to copy it to the correct Folder in Windows.

Where do i need to copy the .iso image so that docker machine will find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experimenting with copying the iso file to following folders it worked (still got errors that it could not get latest version):

```
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Boot2Docker
- C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker
- C:\Users\user_name\.docker\machine
- C:\Users\user_name\.docker\machine\cache\
```

Following happened:

> Running pre-create checks...
>
> (mymachine) Unable to get the latest Boot2Docker ISO release version:  Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest:
>   dial tcp 192.30.253.116:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did  properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond. Creating machine...
>
> (mymachine) Unable to get the
>   latest Boot2Docker ISO release version:  Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest:
>   dial tcp 192.30.253.116:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond.
>
> (mymachine) Copying C:\Users\user_name\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to
>   C:\Users\user_name\.docker\machine\machines\mymachine\boot2docker.iso...
>
> (mymachine) Creating SSH key...
>
> (mymachine) Creating VM...
>
> (mymachine) Using switch "DockerNAT" (mymachine) Creating VHD
>
> ...

From the Output of docker machine:

`(mymachine) Copying C:\Users\user_name\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\user_name\.docker\machine\machines\jit-dev\boot2docker.iso`

I conclude that the correct install location of the Boot2Docker.iso Image is under:
`C:\Users\user_name\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso`

Side note: that the machines are separated by user name on Windows. Having the machine installed on one user does not mean it is available for others.

Comment: For info on the proxy Settings, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489265/docker-boot2docker-set-http-https-proxies-for-docker-on-osx